# How to use Select by Attributes & LIKE operator to find a %

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I have a large data set of points which has the field 'Name'.

Some of the points have an attribute such as 'Slope >40%' or 'Grade 10-30%' for example.

I would like to use Select By Attributes and the LIKE operator to select all points which have a % within the attribute.

I've tried different combinations such as:

WHERE NAME LIKE '%[%]%'

But no luck on trying several combinations...

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the data format involved (if enterprise geodatabase, specify the RDBMS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name LIKE '%$%%' ESCAPE '$'

whatever character comes after the escape character will pick up a % or _ as jsut a regular character instead of special